A system of transitive reputation
I’m curious how the following can be formalized and how it can be proven that the system does or does not have possible undesirable outcomes.
The idea is, in any system, you rely on human trustworthiness, or reputation, for something. Maybe it’s verification of facts, or honesty, or something else.
The way you decide if a person’s contribution should garner them an increase in reputation is the extent to which other trusted people have voted in their favor.
So one place to start in modeling this a bit better might be, people have the ability to cast votes for each other, and the more votes you have, the higher the weight of your vote.
I imagine there are interesting and tricky nuances in trying to define this system formally, and I’m curious if there are ways to prove how the system can be compromised (ie, bad actors coordinate to skew the trust ratings).
Is this a well-known and studied class of algorithms?

This sort of thing has been studied in the literature.  See trust metrics, reputation systems,  Advogato, and Sybil attacks.
